# PHP date increment by month not exceeding last day of month?

Tags: php

I want same day of month for each of the months that fall between start date and end date. Its just that if the month of the day is not valid for a particular month, you want last day of that month. is there any script?. What is have done is.

```
$startdate='2010-01-30';
          $enddate='2011-01-30';
            while ($startdate <= $enddate)
             { 
              echo date('Y-m-d', $startdate ) . "\n";
              $startdate = strtotime('+1 month', $startdate);/// for case of feb 28 days last date it should disply as it skips it
            }
```

Expected out put:
For input `$startdate='2012-01-30'; $enddate='2013-12-30'` Result should be like this ==>

```
    _2012-12-30_
2013-01-30
**2013-02-28**
2013-03-30
2013-04-30
2013-05-30
2013-06-30
2013-07-30
2013-08-30
2013-09-30
2013-10-30
2013-11-30
_2013-12-30_
```

Comment: convert date in timestamp using mktime function, increment month parameter in it

Comment: Try to use `t` parameter of `date` function that will return number of days in each month.

Answer (score 0):

Loop using `for` and adding `$i` months to the start date instead of constantly adding one month to the running value. This way it won't jump to 28th (or 29th) day because of february starting from march.

Comment: @anrdrius sir that means the same if i change loop to for , for each ,do while but output not as expected .